# NullPointer Exception in java code (getting Name of File:null output )

Tags: java

```
 public class HelloWorld

 {

public static int executeLock;
public static int val;
public HelloWorld()
{
    executeLock = 0;
    val = 0;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    new HelloWorld();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try{


            WebFSManager wfm = new WebFSManager();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                      
}).start();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try{
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(10);

                if(executeLock>=2){


                    File f = new WebFSFile("read.js");
                    System.out.println("Name of File :"+f.toString());
                    //FileInputStream f1 = new WebFSFileInputStream(f);
                    //f1.read();
                    //f.deleteOnExit();
                    break;
                }
            }       
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                      
}).start();

}
}
 .........separate file...........................
 public class WebFSFile extends File
 {
String filename;
boolean fileExists;


public WebFSFile(File parent, String child){super(parent,child);}
public WebFSFile(String parent, String child){super(parent,child);} 
public WebFSFile(URI uri) {super(uri);} 
public WebFSFile(String filename) {

    super(filename);

            String script = "<html><body>Hello</body></html>"

           WebFSManager.writeInScriptQueue(script, false);

    String returnVal = WebFSManager.readRawReplyQueue();
    if(returnVal.equals("Error: File or directory not found"))
    {
        fileExists = false;
    }
    else if (Integer.parseInt(returnVal)==1){
        fileExists = true;
    }
    else{
        throw new WebFSClientSideException(returnVal);
    }
    this.filename = filename;
    if(this.filename == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("Null object supplied in WebFSFile constructor");
    }

}
 }
```

WebFSManager is serparate independent class that run's jetty server.when i
 instantiate WebFSFile class object and catch into File object then it jumps to WebFSFile
 constructor and then it delivers the script to WebFSManager and it replys it.but I am
 getting Name of File:null output. so help me

Comment: I just tried it, no it doesn't.

Comment: A word about Java style: class names always start with an uppercase letter and are camel case. Methods always start with lowercase. Also, from your code sample it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to read a file? In that case ``new File("name")`` should be sufficient.

Comment: Is it NullPointerException or "name of file: null"?

Comment: Pick a good Java book. Seriously.

Comment: It printed out: `name of file :hi` for me

Comment: @Sagar Ghuge if we solve your problem, please markt the best answer:Đ

Comment: I know this code works fine bt i have the code of same type in which it gives me null so why is that happening.?

Comment: Post the code that actually gives the error.

Comment: @yoyosagu Can you also put exactly what gets printed? You have a lot of debug prints there please show them to us

Comment: System.out.println("Name of File :"+f.toString()); output of this line is Name of File: null

Comment: @yoyosagu I mean ALL the print statements. Edit them in

Comment: @durron597- you want WebFSManager????

Answer (score 1):

I changed it slightly but:

```
import java.io.*;

public class take
{
  public static void main(String a[])
  {
    File t = new try1("hi");
    System.out.println("name of file :"+t.toString());
  }

  public static class try1 extends File
  {
    public try1(String name) throws NullPointerException
    {
      super(name);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
name of file :hi
```

Comment: send me you mail ID so that i can tell you my actual problem is what..coz i m unable to post my answer due to reputation..code is huge so can't add to comment

Comment: @SagarGhuge edit it into your original post

Answer (score 1):

Docs Oracle:(last row)

```
 File

 public File(String pathname)

Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an 
abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string, 
 then the result is the empty abstract pathname.

Parameters:
    pathname - A pathname string 
Throws:
    NullPointerException - If the pathname argument is null
```

Answer (score -2):

[Consturtor with a one String parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) require a filepath!